# Why is a Vuex value updating a when I don't change it?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm having trouble understanding why Vue devtools says my Vuex data has changed while I only change component specific data() variables.

So i have a Vuex store which holds the fetched chartData that's used to fill up a ChartJS Barchart. This data is passed down through props called `this.chartDividendsProps` to the DividendChart component where I then load the `chartData` into the ChartJS BarChart component.

Now when I press a button that triggers `timeFrameChange(e)` the data in my Vuex is also altered for some reason.

timeFrameChange when a user clicks on the 'year to date' button.
Calls getDividends and setYearToDate

```js
timeFrameChange(e) {
      this.isLoading = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.selectedTimeFrame = e.target.innerText;
        this.isThereData ? this.getDividends() : null;
        this.setYearToDate();
        this.isLoading = false;
      }, 1);
}
```

getDividends from props and load them into this.chartData

```js
getDividends() {
      this.dividendsArray = [];
      this.chartData.datasets = [];

      this.dividendsArray = this.chartDividendsProps // PROPS

      this.chartData.labels = this.dividendsArray[0].datesList;

      // fill stacked chart
      for (let i = 0; i < this.dividendsArray.length; i++) {
        this.chartData.datasets.push({
          label: this.dividendsArray[i].name,
          isin: this.dividendsArray[i].isin,
          backgroundColor: "#007cda",
          borderRadius: 4,
          borderWidth: 0,
          borderSkipped: "bottom",
          borderColor: "transparent",
          borderDash: [10, 5],
          barPercentage: "1",
          hoverBorderColor: "transparent",
          data: this.dividendsArray[i].dividendsList,
        });
      }
    }
}
```

setYearToDate to change the timeframe of the chart

```js
setYearToDate() {
      // delete all months before this year
      let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

      for (let i = 0; i < this.dividendsArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.dividendsArray[i].dividend.length; j++) {
          let dividendYear = parseFloat(this.dividendsArray[i].dividend[j].date.split("-")[1]);

          if (dividendYear < currentYear) {
            this.dividendsArray[i].dividend.splice(j, 1);
            this.dividendsArray[i].datesList.splice(j, 1);
            this.dividendsArray[i].dividendsList.splice(j, 1);
            j--;
          }

        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: you have to get clone of vuex store data and then pass it down to component